# Transformation (x) constraint not doing what its supposed to do, or is it?

Tags: constraints

So recently (about 2 weeks ago) I've started working on a tank model I've been wanting to make for a very long time, okay useless information aside, I want a track to work according to this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FlpCAWgMwRs

I've followed the exact steps this video tells me to do, even to the point of rotating my tracks since his were lined up along the Y axis and mine are aligned with X. What the result is supposed to do is the empty sphere should be a 'controller' on the track moving the right direction and eventually linking with the sprocket to make a flawless track animation. With me the blue relationship line IS moving in circles but the track is not moving whatsoever. Does anybody have a clue what I'm doing wrong here? I work in Blender 3.5.0 while the video is in 2.90.1
I've tried using different curves, different directions and even different constraints / modifiers, applied all transformations, locations, rotations, and scale. And still no result. Anybody who can clear me up on this?